# HTML5 Canvas method getImageData not giving correct result on mousemove when browser zoom

Tags: html, canvas

The question is regarding Canvas in HTML5. I have created a doughnut chart menu in canvas using chartjs.org. Below is the fiddle. I have some arc with colors defined for identifying different modules. when i move mouse on these arc i need to get the corresponding color below the mouse pointer. This works 100% correct when browser is 100% zoom. But, when I set browser to not 100% zoom (say 90% or 75%) then I am not getting correct color code on mouse move below the mouse pointer. This also happens when users are having some different resolution like 1980 x 1020. This happens in chrome only. IF anybody have any idea on the same, will be helpful to me.

```
document.getElementById("canvas").addEventListener('mousemove', function (e) {

    var MainCanvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var MainCanvasCtx = MainCanvas.getContext("2d");

    mouseX = e.clientX - getBodyOffSetLeft(canvas);
    mouseY = e.clientY - getBodyOffSetTop(canvas);
    var p = canvas.getContext('2d').getImageData(mouseX, mouseY, 1, 1).data;
    var hex = "#" + ("000000" + rgbToHex(p[0], p[1], p[2])).slice(-6);
    $("#hex").text(hex + " " + e.screenX + " " + e.offsetX + " " + e.clientX + " " + e.pageX + " " + mouseX);




}, false);
```

here is the fiddle:     http://jsfiddle.net/7eLk2ydn/3/

Comment: If you zoom, in Chrome `getImageData(x,y,1,1).data` sometimes returns more than the 4 bytes of that pixel. I sometimes got 8 or 16 bytes at times while at other times I got 4. If >4, the color and alpha levels will change in those bytes. The information you will get is the one from the interpolated, zoomed graphic it seems.
This is clearly buggy behavior since this is happening sporadically and not consistently on all zoom levels (sometimes happens on 200%, then I zoom in more and it won't happen, zooming back on 200% and it still won't happen, zooming in/out more and it happens again).